# In VS Code, how can I hide the shortcut hints that appear when all editors are closed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to hide this:

[image]

More accurately, it appears when only one editor group is open and it has no editors. It does not appear when there are multiple empty editor groups (which is possible when `workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups` is `false`).

I am doing videos using VS Code and I would like to have an empty startup screen.

Comment: open an empty file and close VSC, then start VSC

Comment: @rioV8 It doesn't work down there :(

Comment: same question, is there an answer?

Answer (score 5):

This can be disabled with **Workbench > Tips: Enabled** setting (toggle). Or just add `"workbench.tips.enabled": false` in `settings.json`

Not sure if this disables anything else though. This also leaves VS Code logo enabled. [User and Workspace Settings Docs says](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> When enabled, will show the watermark tips when no editor is open.